# Spring : Logging not working with log4j or logback

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am trying to get logging working again. Unfortunately, sometime back it just stopped working, I don't know what is causing that. I tried some suggestions on net, but nothing useful. Any suggestions?

Pom.xml :

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.9.Final</hibernate.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <springsecurity.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <spring-platform.version>1.1.3.RELEASE</spring-platform.version>
        <jetty.version>9.2.9.v20150224</jetty.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

  <!-- Spring framework dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring security dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have both log4j.xml and logback.xml :

log4j.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>


    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
  <logger name="org.cometd">
        <level value="debug"/>
    </logger>
    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

logback.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>


    <logger name="org.cometd" level="debug"/>
    <logger name="com.tooltank.spring.chat.ChatServiceImpl" level="info"/>
</configuration>
```

During server startup I get this :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home//WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
13:43:29,173 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
13:43:29,173 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
13:43:29,174 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/path/to/logback.xml]
13:43:29,292 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
13:43:29,298 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - Could not find resource corresponding to [org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml]
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
13:43:29,299 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.cometd] to DEBUG
13:43:29,299 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.tooltank.spring.chat.ChatServiceImpl] to INFO
13:43:29,299 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
13:43:29,300 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@59474a9e - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using log4j and logback in one application. If you have both jars in your classpath the classloader will pick either one of them (kind of random..) 
That is indicated by this log statement:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
```

If you intend to use logback you need to place the logback.xml file in the classpath of your application. From documentation:

> logback will try to configure itself using the files logback-test.xml or logback.xml if found on the class path.

You can also check out this link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging

Edit: 
I guess you also need to add an appender to the console such as:

```
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<!-- encoders are assigned the type
     ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
<encoder>
  <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

and then add the appender to your logger:

```
<logger name="org.cometd" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>
```

Best regards!

Comment: Looking at the current situation, what would you recommend, remove log4j or logback, whichever is easier to manage and I can get logs from libraries with debug and so.

Comment: My personal favorite would be to keep logback but it depends what you need. Check out the link that I added in my answer. I guess that could help you

Comment: Hi, I have removed all the dependencies for log4j and slf4j, and only kept logback-classic and logback-core from ch.qos.logback. The configuration of the xml is same what I have as you gave in the link.  Even after that I cannot see debug messages, any ideas. Startup log : http://pastebin.com/pSdmY77U

Comment: Did you specify an appender in the logback.xml? Such as:

Comment: I guess you need to define the appender as well as in my example above.

Comment: It still complains about encoder not being set, even though I have it. Here is the complete logback.xml with log and entire POM.xml, can you please just tell me what change do I need to make rather than in parts, its causing confusion, thank you. Link : http://pastebin.com/Z1bKVN1W

Comment: This one works on my machine: http://pastebin.com/9khXCh4Z. You can also remove line 17 then

Comment: This worked on my system as well. Thanks a lot... :-) Don't know what I was missing?

Comment: The xml was corrupt. The appender didn't include the encoder tags

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I had mixed both `<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>` & `<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>` dependencies together.
After I remove `<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>` and keep only `<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>` logs are started to written.