# logback - Debug Level does not work

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have a JAVA EE application that uses logback (intended as a successor to the popular log4j project)

Here the `logback.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <!-- trace, debug, info, warn, error, fatal -->
    <timestamp key="myTimestamp" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH-mm-ss.SSS"/>  


    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <!-- To enable JMX Management -->
    <jmxConfigurator/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"}  [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>telefonica.log</file> 

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>telefonica.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>             
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>



    <logger name="com.telefonica”                      level="debug" />
    <logger name="org.springframework"             level="debug" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.web"         level="debug" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.security"    level="debug" />

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

In 1 of the class inside the package `com.telefonica` I have this code

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TS.class);

log.debug ("logging to WS " + WS_VERSION);
```

and I don't see anything in the console, but I see it when I put  `log.info ("logging to WS " + WS_VERSION);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding appender to your logger like below

```
<logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
<level value="DEBUG" />
<appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>
```

PLease refer this question and solution

[Spring : Logging not working with log4j or logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186027/spring-logging-not-working-with-log4j-or-logback)

Answer (score 0):

Change your logger level to `level="DEBUG"` from `INFO`

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG"/>
```

Comment: add this <configuration debug="true"> . It will help us to find out the config issues

Comment: I tried your solution. Nothing ... It's doesn't change any more

Answer (score 0):

Just adding something that worked for me for a similar scenario.

I chanced to have both `logback.xml` and `application.properties` in my classpath for a **Spring Boot** application. In my `application.properties` I had

```
logging.level.root=INFO
```

which effectively narrowed down anything that got handled by Logback, so settings in `logback.xml` seemed to have no effect as far as the log levels lower than INFO were concertned.